# Problem with rotation around the center OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have a problem with rotation around the center of an object.
I have a plane and I found out its center x,y the z for translation is used for moving.

I want to rotate that around it is center, but not around 0,0,0
But it keeps that way.

Can you give me some advice how to get it work?

```
glRotatef(moveLeftRight, 1,0,0);
glTranslatef(xT,yT, thrustP);
```

xT and yT are the points, thrustP is Z like moving. MoveLeftRight - rotation.

Comment: The matrix multiplication is not [commutativ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). Do `glTranslatef` before `glRotatef`.

Comment: When I do that it stopped rotating .

Comment: I can like rotate that but only at the z axis not moving like left or righ only at the place when it is moving.

Comment: It's not quite clear, but if you're trying to "orbit" the view around a particular point, then sometimes it's easier to split up building the matrix into steps. For example: 1) translate to the center point, 2) rotate in the 2 axes you care about, and then 3) pull out/in using a translate in 1 dimension now that you're in "orbit" space.

Comment: Easiest way is translate so the center of rotation IS at 0,0,0, then rotate, then do the opposite translation